# How to properly import @brainhubeu/react-carousel in nextjs

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I have been trying to use @brainhubeu/react-carousel in nextjs without success.
I have used `next/dynamic` with `ssr=false` because of SSR. Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";
import small from "../../../images/app-small-book.jpg";
import Image from "next/image";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import "@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css";

const { default: Carousel, Dots } = dynamic(
  () => require("@brainhubeu/react-carousel") ,
  { ssr: false }
);

export default function MyCarousel() {
  return (
    <Carousel plugins={["arrows"]}>
      <img src={small} />
      <img src={small} />
      <img src={small} />
    </Carousel>
  );

  function Stuff() {
    return (
      <div className="flex py-1">
        <div>
          <Image alt="twitter" src={small} />
        </div>
        <div className="pl-2">
          <p className="sm:text-sm lg:text-base text-xxs font-bold ">
            Our Book One
          </p>
          <p className="sm:text-xs lg:text-sm text-xxs  ">Our Author One</p>
          <p className="sm:text-xs text-xxs font-bold">Ksh. 30</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I use tailwind in my project and after searching around I modified `postcss.config.js` Not sure if this helps, but didn't make a difference.

```
const purgecss = [
  "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
  {`enter code here`
    content: [
      "./node_modules/@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css",
      "./node_modules/@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css.map",
      "./node_modules/react-toastify/dist/*.css",
      "./components/**/*.js",
      "./pages/**/*.js",
    ],
    defaultExtractor: (content) => {
      const broadMatches = content.match(/[^<>"'`\s]*[^<>"'`\s:]/g) || [];
      const innerMatches = content.match(/[^<>"'`\s.()]*[^<>"'`\s.():]/g) || [];
      return broadMatches.concat(innerMatches);
    },
  },
];

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

This is the error I get in VScode:

```
error - Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Any help will be appreciated. Including alternative carousels for nextjs.

Comment: Try loading `Carousel` as `const Carousel = dynamic(() => import("@brainhubeu/react-carousel"), { ssr: false });` instead.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work, ended up using [react-alice-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alice-carousel) package instead. Works really well.